# how to count each hour to one day with mysql

Tags: mysql

I have query like this

```
select 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(createdtime,10),'-',''),':',''),'T','') as paydate, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='SUCCESS' AND issync='1' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumpaid, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='SUCCESS' AND issync in ('3','4') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumfail, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='CLOSED' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumclose, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='NULL' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumunflag 
from 
    tb_r_orderdata 
WHERE 
    tb_r_orderdata.createdtime IS NOT NULL 
group by 
    tb_r_orderdata.createdtime 
ORDER by 
    tb_r_orderdata.createdtime ASC
```

[image]

In the output I want something like

```
20170725 7 3 4 3 
20170726 5 6 2 4
```

Comment: You could save yourself a world of pain, not to mention improving performance, by adhering to proper data types.

Comment: @Strawberry thank you

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords (like `select`, `from` etc.) - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or write them in all lowercase (select, from), or in mixed case (Select, From) - but please **pick one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix all of them together! (like `order BY`.....)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, i'll do it. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your group by and order by to paydate?

```
select 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(createdtime,10),'-',''),':',''),'T','') as paydate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='SUCCESS' AND issync='1' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumpaid, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='SUCCESS' AND issync in ('3','4') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumfail, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='CLOSED' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumclose, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status='NULL' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as sumunflag 
from 
    tb_r_orderdata 
WHERE 
    tb_r_orderdata.createdtime IS NOT NULL 
group by 
    paydate 
ORDER by 
    paydate ASC
```

Comment: i forgot to change it, thank you so much for your help